# issue requesting db result set after sometimes, i do make a request to sql but i don,t receive any error in logs only loader is visible

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, eclipselink

My DaoImpl works for some hours, then I don't know why when I make a request to it. It does not respond. Loading process in browser is waiting for response even it makes request to db procedure,
after every 2 minutes the same request is again raise in the logs without requesting by clicking button and it keeps happening to hit db proc continuously every 2 second but not getting result set, the control gets stuck after firing executemethod()  to get dbresultset and its only happening in this daoimpl rest all procedures work fine.

No thread concept has been implemented manually, the issue is only taking place in prod environment

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/roomListing"}, method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView roomInvoiceLisitng(@ModelAttribute final RoomInvoiceForm vRoomInvoiceForm, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    LOGGER.info("inside RoominvoiceController :: roomInvoiceLisitng()::chreq::"+vRoomInvoiceForm.getChreq());
    LOGGER.info("inside RoominvoiceController :: roomInvoiceLisitng()::chreq::"+request.getParameter("chreq"));
    LOGGER.info("inside RoominvoiceController :: roomInvoiceLisitng()::propId::"+request.getParameter("propId"));

    

    
    ModelAndView model=null;
    String vPropId;
    String ChannelProp_id;
    String vCard_details_privliedge = null;
    String vINCDflag = null;
    String chreq="";
    
    
    String path = request.getContextPath();
    String sessionId;
    String uniqueID=null;
    ArrayList<RoomInvoiceDto> vProductServiceInfo = new ArrayList<RoomInvoiceDto>();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    try{
        //HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        LOGGER.info("sessionid:"+session.getId());
        chreq=ResUtil.checkNull(request.getParameter("chreq")).equals("")?vRoomInvoiceForm.getChreq():ResUtil.checkNull(request.getParameter("chreq"));
        
        
    
        if(ResUtil.checkNull(chreq).equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
            //sessionId=(String)session.getAttribute("sessionId");
            //ChannelProp_id=(String)session.getAttribute("ChannelProp_id");
            vPropId=ResUtil.checkNull(request.getParameter("propId")).equalsIgnoreCase("")?vRoomInvoiceForm.getPropId():ResUtil.checkNull(request.getParameter("propId"));
        }else{
            vPropId=(String) session.getAttribute("Prop_id");
            //sessionId=session.getId();
        }       
        
        /*if(!ResUtil.checkNull(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSessionId()).equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            uniqueID=vRoomInvoiceForm.getSessionId();
        }else{
             uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }*/
        LOGGER.info("sessionId:"+uniqueID);
        LOGGER.info("session:"+session);
        LOGGER.info("propId:"+vPropId);
        User_Refund=(String) session.getAttribute("User_Refund");
        LOGGER.info("inside RoominvoiceController :: refund flag"+User_Refund);
        
        RoomInvoiceForm pRoomInvoiceForm=vRoomInvoiceService.roomInvoiceList(vRoomInvoiceForm, vPropId,request, response);
        
    model= new ModelAndView("room-invoice/roominvoice_listing","vRoomList",pRoomInvoiceForm.getvRoomInvoiceList());
    model.addObject("RoomInvoiceForm", pRoomInvoiceForm);
    
    model.addObject("errorMsg", request.getAttribute("errorMsg"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.info("roomInvoiceListing:"+e);
    }   
    return model;
    
}
```

DAO Implementation

````
@Override
    public RoomInvoiceForm roomInvoiceList(RoomInvoiceForm vRoomInvoiceForm,String vProp_Id, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        LOGGER.info("----------------- Start of RomInvoiceDaoImpl :: getroomInvoiceList() -------------");
        String vIsError=null;
        String vErrorDesc=null;
        Integer pageCount=0;
        Integer totalPage=0;
        RowSet dbResultSet = null;
        //HttpSession vSession = request.getSession(false);
        Procedure vProcedure = ProcedureFactory.getProcedure();
        ProcedureMetaData vProcedureMeta;
        ArrayList<RoomInvoiceDto> vRoomList = new ArrayList<RoomInvoiceDto>();```

        //String vPattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        //String dateInString =new SimpleDateFormat(vPattern).format(new Date());

        try {
            LOGGER.info("----------------- Start try block RomInvoiceDaoImpl :: getroomInvoiceList() -------------");
            vProcedureMeta = new ProcedureMetaData("pr$roominvoice_search_newmars_temp");
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(ResUtil.checkNull(vProp_Id),java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);                                                                      //1 propId
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchPaymentStatus()==null?"":vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchPaymentStatus(),java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);     //2 mod_status
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchInvoice()==null?"":vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchInvoice(),java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);                 //3 mod invoiceno   
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchEmail()==null?"":vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchEmail(),java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);                     //4 mod_cust_mail
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchLastName()==null?"":vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchLastName(),java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);               //5 lastname
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchAmount()==null?0.00:Double.parseDouble(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchAmount()),java.sql.Types.DOUBLE,false);//6 amt
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchRefenceNo()==null?"":vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchRefenceNo(),java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);             //7 search by ref
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchDateType()==null?"":vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchDateType(),java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);               //8 search by
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchFromDate()==null?"":vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchFromDate(),java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);               //9 from Date
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchToDate()==null?"":vRoomInvoiceForm.getSearchToDate(),java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);                   //10 To Date
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter("", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR, false);                                        //11 export flag
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter("",java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,false);                                                                                             //12 room type
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getPageNumber(),java.sql.Types.INTEGER,false);                                                             //13 pageNumber
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(vRoomInvoiceForm.getPageSize(),java.sql.Types.INTEGER,false);                                                               //14 pageSize
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(0,java.sql.Types.INTEGER,true);         //15  pageSize
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(0,java.sql.Types.INTEGER,true);         //16  page Number   
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(null,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,true);      //17 error
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(null,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,true);      //18 error_desc 
            vProcedureMeta.addParameter(null,ProcedureMetaData.TYPE_CURSOR,true);//19 cursor
            if(vProcedureMeta != null){ 
                LOGGER.info("roomInvoiceList :: vProcedureMeta");
                ProcedureMetaData procedureMetaOut = vProcedure.execute(vProcedureMeta);
                LOGGER.info("roomInvoiceList :: vProcedureMeta:"+procedureMetaOut.getDbConnectionType());
                pageCount = (Integer)(procedureMetaOut.getParameterByindex(15)).getOutputValue();
                totalPage = (Integer)(procedureMetaOut.getParameterByindex(16)).getOutputValue();
                vIsError = (String)(procedureMetaOut.getParameterByindex(17)).getOutputValue();
                vErrorDesc = (String)(procedureMetaOut.getParameterByindex(18)).getOutputValue();
                dbResultSet = (RowSet)(procedureMetaOut.getParameterByindex(19).getOutputValue());
                vRoomInvoiceForm.setPageCount(pageCount);
                vRoomInvoiceForm.setTotalPage(totalPage);
                vRoomInvoiceForm.setPageNumber(vRoomInvoiceForm.getPageNumber());
                vRoomInvoiceForm.setPageSize(vRoomInvoiceForm.getPageSize());
                vRoomInvoiceForm.setTotalCount(totalPage);
                
                LOGGER.info("vIsError:"+vIsError+"\t"+"vIsError Desc"+vErrorDesc+"\t"+"totalPage:"+totalPage+"\t"+"pageCount:"+pageCount);
                if(dbResultSet!=null){
                    while(dbResultSet.next() ){
                        RoomInvoiceDto vRoomInvoiceDto= new RoomInvoiceDto();
                        
                        
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setINV_CRT_DATE(dbResultSet.getString("INV_CRT_DATE"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_status(dbResultSet.getString("mod_status"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_mer_orderno(dbResultSet.getString("mod_mer_orderno"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMode_Arrival(dbResultSet.getString("Mode_Arrival"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMode_Departure(dbResultSet.getString("Mode_Departure"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setInv_exe_date(dbResultSet.getString("Inv_exe_date"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_amt(dbResultSet.getString("mod_amt"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMobile_num(dbResultSet.getString("mobile_num"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_cust_mail(dbResultSet.getString("mod_cust_mail"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setInvoice_send_by(dbResultSet.getString("invoice_send_by"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setRb_id(dbResultSet.getString("rb_id"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setRb_order_no(dbResultSet.getString("rb_order_no"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setCurr_id(dbResultSet.getString("curr_id"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setRbd_total_amt(dbResultSet.getString("rbd_total_amt"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setRbd_original_amt(dbResultSet.getString("rbd_original_amt"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_checksum(dbResultSet.getString("mod_checksum"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setTracking_id(dbResultSet.getString("tracking_id"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setPatial_amt_per(dbResultSet.getString("patial_amt_per"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setPatial_amt_flat(dbResultSet.getString("patial_amt_flat"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_id(dbResultSet.getString("mod_id"));
                        //vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_refno(dbResultSet.getString("mod_refno"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_cust_first_name(dbResultSet.getString("mod_cust_first_name"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_cust_last_name(dbResultSet.getString("mod_cust_last_name"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setInv_created_by(dbResultSet.getString("inv_created_by"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setSettele_date(dbResultSet.getString("settele_date"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_refund_date(dbResultSet.getString("mod_refund_date"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setMod_refund_amt(dbResultSet.getString("mod_refund_amt"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setTrans_log_id(dbResultSet.getString("trans_log_id"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setGtw_id(dbResultSet.getString("gtw_id"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setRefund_flag(dbResultSet.getString("refund_flag"));
                        vRoomInvoiceDto.setActivity(dbResultSet.getString("Activity"));
                        //vRoomInvoiceDto.setAgent(dbResultSet.getString("agent"));
                        vRoomList.add(vRoomInvoiceDto);
                    }
                }               
                vRoomInvoiceForm.setvRoomInvoiceList(vRoomList);
                //LOGGER.info("-----------------Size Of  RoomInvoiceDaoImpl :: getroomInvoiceList() -------------"+e);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.info("----------------- Exception in  RoomInvoiceDaoImpl :: getroomInvoiceList() -------------"+e);

            }
        finally{
            try{
                if(dbResultSet != null) {
                    LOGGER.info("----------------- Finally in  RoomInvoiceDaoImpl :: getroomInvoiceList() -------------");
                    dbResultSet.close();
                    }
                vProcedure.closeResources();                    
            }
            catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        LOGGER.info("----------------- End of RoomInvoiceDaoImpl :: getroomInvoiceList() -------------");
        return vRoomInvoiceForm;

    }
````

Comment: Comments don't make it clear the timing of what is going on, or more specifically, when. Is it retrying the operation every 2 minutes once you hit the endpoint via REST or is it every 2 seconds? Sounds like you might be using a REST client that retries GET requests automatically, while if something is hitting the database every 2 seconds, something configured internally to retry on errors. Turn on logging and give details on what exactly is being issued to the database (if using EclipseLink, logging on finest will help). First guess is your datasource is disconnected after inactivity

Comment: @chris as soon as vProcedure.execute() method is call the control just stop and nothing get prints after that, and after every 2 minutes  being passed the same request for the resource is again getting print in log

Comment: @chris how should i disconnect the datasource if my control not getting inside finally block?

Comment: I was NOT suggesting to disconnect your DS, I was suggesting it was disconnected. If it isn't returning - get a stack dump and check out where it is getting stuck. There are numerous posts on how to debug something that isn't returning. Otherwise, it is throwing something, maybe a Throwable that you just aren't catching, or it could be timing out or locking at the database level. We have no idea what this procedure is or does, so no way to know how to debug it. Try a simple select to validate your DS and connections before running this code if that is possible.

Comment: @Chris i am already printing exception in Log, but i can,t see any issue getting printing ,just same proc request is getting raised every 2 min logs getting print till execute method , this issue is happening only in production environment, its working fine in Local environment, i will post the logs here with 2 min time cycle what getting print there, is there anything related to thread that,s get halt or wait or sleep mode , can i trace it ?

Comment: Exception != Throwable which is what I suggested you try looking for, but regardless, you need to debug your production app or where ever this reproduces, to find the issue. If it is a thread taking longer than 2 minutes to return, taking a thread dump will tell you where that process is at the moment you get the dump. You will have to look into the options available to your production environment, and the technologies involved to see if they are catching exceptions and have logging capabilities you can enable to tell you what is happening. Nothing here is EclipseLink which you've tagged

Comment: @Chris is there any example link how to configure thread dump in entire application via code so that i can log thread which is running like logger, it will help me very much